# Error Windows Server 2008: El programa lanzó un comando pero la longitud del comando es incorrecta

Tags: seguridad, windows-server

Estoy trabajando con Windows Server 2008, concretamente en el ámbito de copias de seguridad. Quiero copiar el contenido de un disco local (denominado Disco Local F) al directorio que he configurado como carpeta compartida de la máquina virtual y la máquina real en VirtualBox. Intento seguir los pasos que se muestran en estas imágenes:

[image: Inicio del asistente]

[image: Seleccionar configuración de copia de seguridad]

[image: Seleccionar elementos de copia de seguridad]

[image: Especificar tipo de destino]

[image: Especificar carpeta remota]

[image: Especificar opción avanzada]

[image: Confirmación]

Cuando confirmo la copia de seguridad se produce este error:
[image: Error que se produce]

He comprobado que los archivos del disco no se encuentran dañados, vaciar la carpeta compartida por si se trataba de una cuestión de espacio, además de activar la detección de redes y el uso compartido de archivos, pero no logro ver el motivo, siendo algo que me parece extraño, ya que he realizado copias del contenido de un disco en otro, no apareciendo el error en ningún momento.
Muchas gracias de antemano por las respuestas.

Comment: esto que tiene que ver con programacion???

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].